# How to align label with prop.search in a row?

Tags: python, panel

I have this piece of code here:

```
 def draw(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row() 
        row.label(text='Armature:', text_ctxt='', translate=True, icon='NONE', icon_value=0) 
        row.label(text=bpy.context.active_object.name, text_ctxt='', translate=True, icon='NONE', icon_value=0)       
        #col = layout.column() 
        row = layout.row() 
        row.prop_search(scn, "collection_for_assignment", bpy.data, "collections", text = "Collection")  
        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator(AssignObjectsToArmatureOperator.bl_idname, text="Assign objects", icon="BONE_DATA")
```

and the result is:

[image]

but i would like to have "objects and armature.002" aligned like so:

[image]

i tried "aligned=True" and different col/row combinations, but obviously i didn't understand how to use row/cols right.

--

i am very sorry if my arrow wasn't clear enough:

I want the name of the armature aligned to the next row (collection:objects) like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to simply combine the 2 pieces of information into the same line:
`row.label(text='Armature: ' + bpy.context.active_object.name, text_ctxt='', translate=True, icon='NONE', icon_value=0)`

But that's no fun....
Using columns and adjusting their spacing factor is much more interesting...

```
 def draw(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        split = layout.split(factor=0.2)
        col_1 = split.column()
        col_2 = split.column()
        #row = layout.row() 
        col_1.label(text='Armature:', text_ctxt='', translate=True, icon='NONE', icon_value=0) 
        col_2.label(text=bpy.context.active_object.name, text_ctxt='', translate=True, icon='NONE', icon_value=0)       
        #col = layout.column() 
        row = layout.row() 
        row.prop_search(scn, "collection_for_assignment", bpy.data, "collections", text = "Collection")  
        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator(AssignObjectsToArmatureOperator.bl_idname, text="Assign objects", icon="BONE_DATA")
```

The issue with this approach is that they keep a distance ratio between them, meaning that as the panel is resized the gap between them will also resize keeping the factor.

To keep the 2 together I'd use the first approach, it also has the benefit of simpler code.

**EDIT**
As the prop_search item doesn't seem to have the ability to set the distance between it's text and it's data, I'm not sure that  what you want is possible (might be, but I can't find a way)
Using the `layout.split(factor=0.24)` method above might be your only option here. I found a factor or 0.24 gave a fairly good result. It does change as the panel grows but so does the data box in the prop_search so they stay very close.

[image]

Comment: Hi Psyonic, thank you very much for your time and your answer. I am sorry that my question was misleading. I improved my question and i hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I noticed that just after I posted my answer, I'll update it

Comment: thank you for the update